# Are there any instances where non-Greco-Roman goddesses fall in love with mortals?

Tags: myth-identification, comparative

However, I will not be taking into account the Greco-Roman and Mesopotamian stories as they are the only stories that I know of in which a goddess loves a human.

Comment: https://japanesemythology.wordpress.com/swan-maidens-and-the-white-feather-on-his-head/

Comment: Would be nice to mention in question those Greco-Roman and Mesopotamian stories you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple that I could find.

Clídna, the Irish goddess/Fairy Queen, had an affair with Ciabhan, John Fitzjames, and Earl Gerald Fitzgerald, among others.[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=nd9R6GQBB_0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Cl%C3%ADodhna&f=false)

Bai Mudan was worshiped as a goddess who tempted men with sex. It's not quite love, but it's close. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bai_Mudan_(mythology))

The West African [Mami Wata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mami_Wata) spirits are analogous to Greek nymphs. They seem to fall in love, not just want sex, too.

Saxo [mentions](http://www.wyrdwords.vispa.com/goddesses/frigg/saxo.html) that Frigg slept with a servant, but Saxo had a Christian agenda and stated up front that he believed Frigg and Odin were actually people, not gods.

Answer (score 6):

In the Irish tale The [Sickbed of Cuchulainn](http://www.luminarium.org/mythology/ireland/cuchulainnsick.htm) the hero has an affair with Fand, a fairy woman. It ends unhappily, as the otherworld and this world cannot be together. Fand returns to her husband, the sea-god and magician [Manannan mac Lir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manann%C3%A1n_mac_Lir), and Cuchulainn goes back to his wife, Emer. To make sure they never meet again, Manannan shakes his cloak between Cuchulainn and Fand.